# Is "Finish him" grammatically correct or must it be "Finish him off"?

Tags: grammar

I know it's just "Finish him" in Mortal Kombat, but is it really grammatically correct when, say, writing dialogues for characters in a story (eg. a villain saying the line in a superhero story)? All dictionaries say it's "finish him off."

Comment: Your wooden statue of George Washington looks pretty good, but it lacks varnish.  You need to finish him off. ???

Comment: I think you need to edit to clarify that in _Mortal Kombat_ "Finish him" is what the games announces as an instruction to deliver the _coup de grâce_ to an already-defeated player: not everyone knows this!

Comment: Not to be confused with _Finnish him_, which is an order to speak to him in long words with too many vowels.

Answer (score 1):

*Grammatically* "Finish him" is an imperative verb with a direct object, and is completely normal: like "Eat it".

*Lexically*, "finish" meaning "kill" is less common than "finish off"; but it does occur.

The iWeb corpus has 2060 instances of "finish/es/ed him off" and 3323 of "finish/es/ed him" (including the 2060).